# React setState not changing state

Tags: reactjs, state

I isolated the bug I was having into 1 tiny file:

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      toggle: true
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('toggle before: ' + this.state.toggle);
    this.setState((state) => {
      return {toggle: !state.toggle}
    }, () => console.log('toggle after: ' + this.state.toggle));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>{this.state.toggle ? 'true' : 'false'}</div>
    );
  }
}

function App() {
  return (
    <Test></Test>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This App has 1 job: create a state 'toggle' to true, then change it to false after it mounts.

The console output of this page is:

> toggle before: true

> toggle after: true

The state is just not changing!! wtf! I'm more of a beginner to React, but I've used state many many times with no issue; I don't know why things stop working in this case.

Comment: This just looks like a typo, you have `return {toggle: !state.toggle}`, you're missing the `this`. It should be `return {toggle: !this.state.toggle}`

Comment: @Jayce444 Nah, reading the state that was passed as the first argument to the updater function is the correct way when using an updater function.

Comment: @Lennholm hmm weird. I put OP's code into a sandbox, as he said it doesn't work, but adding the `this` made it start working. I haven't used class components and `setState` for a while so I might need to refresh my knowledge to see what exactly is the issue here

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any reason to use an updater function instead of a plain state change object in this case. If you change the `setState` call to the following it should work as you expect:

```
this.setState({toggle: !this.state.toggle}, () => console.log('toggle after: ' + this.state.toggle));
```

When using an updater function, React invokes it twice. I'm not sure exactly why but it seems to be in order to reveal bugs that could be caused by the updater function not being pure. Though it seems to me that it should at least invoke the updater function with identical state objects both times.

Comment: This works, but I don't understand why. If React invoked updater functions twice, I would expect to see in my console:  
>toggle before: true
>toggle after: false
>toggle before: false
>toggle after: true

Comment: @Henry When I tested your code, I saw `toggle before: true` - `toggle after: false` - `toggle after: true`. Only the updater function gets invoked twice, not the `componentDidMount` method, so the "toggle before" message only gets logged once. I still haven't been able to figure out why React does this.